# mkdir: missing operand - ssh -tt ${REMOTE_SERVER} sudo sh -c "mkdir -p /opt/migration"

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Given:

```
MIGRATION_FOLDER=/opt/migration
```

Either this:

```
ssh -tt ${REMOTE_SERVER} sudo sh -c "mkdir -p /opt/migration"
```

or this:

```
ssh -tt ${REMOTE_SERVER} sudo sh -c "mkdir -p '$MIGRATION_FOLDER'"
```

returns:

> mkdir: missing operand

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra level of quoting.

```
ssh -tt ${REMOTE_SERVER} sudo sh -c "'mkdir -p \"$MIGRATION_FOLDER\"'"
```

or:

```
ssh -tt ${REMOTE_SERVER} "sudo sh -c 'mkdir -p \"$MIGRATION_FOLDER\"'"
```

If you need to execute multiple commands, put them all inside the single quotes.

```
ssh -tt ${REMOTE_SERVER} "sudo sh -c 'rm -rf \"$MIGRATION_FOLDER\"; mkdir -p \"$MIGRATION_FOLDER\"'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I am assuming several commands would be like this:
**ssh -tt ${REMOTE_SERVER} "sudo sh -c 'rm -rf \"$MIGRATION_FOLDER\"'; 'mkdir -p \"$MIGRATION_FOLDER\"'"**

Comment: No, you should just have one set of quotes around the entire argument after `-c`.

Comment: `-c 'rm -rf \"$MIGRATION_FOLDER\"; mkdir -p \"$MIGRATION_FOLDER\"'`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed